# How to test a Connexion/Flask app?

Tags: python, flask, swagger, pytest, connexion

I'm using the [Connexion](https://github.com/zalando/connexion) framework for [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) to build a microservice. I would like to write tests for my application using `py.test`.

In the `pytest-flask` doc it says to create a fixture in `conftest.py` that creates the app like so:

#### `conftest.py`

```
import pytest

from api.main import create_app


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app()
    return app
```

In my test I'm using the `client` fixture like this:

#### `test_api.py`

```
def test_api_ping(client):
    res = client.get('/status')
    assert res.status == 200
```

However when I run `py.test` I get the following error message:

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_______________________ ERROR at setup of test_api_ping ________________________

request = <SubRequest '_monkeypatch_response_class' for <Function 'test_api_ping'>>
monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch instance at 0x7f9f76b76518>

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def _monkeypatch_response_class(request, monkeypatch):
        """Set custom response class before test suite and restore the original
        after. Custom response has `json` property to easily test JSON responses::
    
            @app.route('/ping')
            def ping():
                return jsonify(ping='pong')
    
            def test_json(client):
                res = client.get(url_for('ping'))
                assert res.json == {'ping': 'pong'}
    
        """
        if 'app' not in request.fixturenames:
            return
    
        app = request.getfuncargvalue('app')
        monkeypatch.setattr(app, 'response_class',
>                           _make_test_response_class(app.response_class))
E       AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'response_class'
```

How can I make `py.test` work? Here is my `create_app` function:

#### `main.py`

```
import connexion


def create_app():
    app = connexion.App(__name__, port=8002,)
    app.add_api('swagger.yaml')
    return app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_app().run()
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Using fixtures

**test_api.py**

```
import pytest
import connexion

flask_app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__)
flask_app.add_api('swagger.yml')


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client():
    with flask_app.app.test_client() as c:
        yield c


def test_health(client):
    response = client.get('/health')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

**swagger.yml**

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: My API
  version: '1.0'
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
schemes:
  - https
paths:
  /health:
    get:
      tags: [Health]
      operationId: api.health
      summary: Health Check
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Status message from server describing current health
```

**api.py**

```
def health():
    return {'msg': 'ok'}, 200
```

#### Using Swagger Tester

Another solution using [swagger-tester](https://github.com/Trax-air/swagger-tester):

**test_api.py**

```
from swagger_tester import swagger_test

authorize_error = {
    'get': {
        '/health': [200],
    }
}

def test_swagger():
    swagger_test('swagger.yml', authorize_error=authorize_error)
```

Cool thing about this library is that you can use the examples provided in your spec. But I don't think it works out of the box with `connexion.RestyResolver`: you'll have to specify the OperationId at each endpoint.

Comment: This actually worked for me once. However, now it has started failing again, not sure why: `E       AttributeError: 'FlaskClient' object has no attribute 'response_class'`

Comment: I had the actually name the fixture something else than `app`

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pytest
from json import JSONEncoder
import pytest
from connexion import App

SWAGGER_PATH = "path_to_directory_that_containes_swagger_file"

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = App(__name__, specification_dir=SWAGGER_PATH)
    app.app.json_encoder = JSONEncoder
    app.add_api("swagger.yaml")
    app_client = app.app.test_client()
    return app_client


def test_health(app) -> None:
    """
    :except: success
    """
    response = app.get("/health", content_type='application/json')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

For more info check [this](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#fixtures).