# Why ModuleNotFoundError occurs when running connexion test

Tags: python, flask, swagger

I am having problem with testing of a swagger application in python. The error returned was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'routes.dataservices'

I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934525/how-to-test-a-connexion-flask-app) which I referred to but is still not working. The only difference I see is that my current python codes are placed in a folder called **routes**.

**swagger.yml**

```
paths:
  /leaderboard:
    get:
      tags:
        - Data Services
      summary: Get leaderboard
      operationId: routes.dataservices.get_leaderboard
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/LeaderList'
        400:
          description: Retrieval error
          content: {}
```

**dataservices.py**

```
def get_leaderboard():
    return {'msg': 'ok'}, 200
```

**test_api.py**

```
import pytest
import connexion

flask_app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__, specification_dir='../specs/')
flask_app.add_api('swagger.yml')


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client():
    with flask_app.app.test_client() as c:
        yield c


def test_ui(client):
    response = client.get('/v0.1/ui')
    assert response.status_code == 308
```

**Directory structure**

```
├── main
│   └── routes
│       └── dataservices.py
│   └── specs
│       └── swagger.yml
│   └── tests
│       └── test-api.py
```

Comment: Did you add an `__init__.py` in your `routes` folder ?

Comment: I just added the file and the content -> from routes.dataservices import *
But the error still maintains: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'routes.dataservices'